# How do I disable TinyTAN avatars on BTS songs?

Tags: beat-saber

Sometimes while playing Beat Saber's BTS Music Pack, TinyTAN avatars will appear mid-song and start flying around. The extra distraction makes it difficult to play Expert or Expert+ tracks.

Is there a way to disable these BTS avatars?

[image: A TinyTAN avatar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The BTS TinyTAN avatars won't appear if you override the default environment or disable environmental effects**.

To change your environment, go to the Solo song menu, click the "Environments" tab on the settings menu, and enable "Override Default Environments". You can then select any environment that isn't BTS.

(*Note: Lighting & environment effects won't appear when playing BTS songs in environments released after the Lady Gaga pack due to the updated [Group Lighting System](https://beatsaber.com/documentation/environment-specific-lighting-attributes-and-explanations/index.html)*)

[image: Override default environment]
<sub>Screenshot from [Auli Nikkanen - Beat Saber, Adjust Settings (0:23)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPWxqG0EvmI)</sub>

To disable environmental effects, go to Solo song menu, click the "Player Options" tab on the settings menu, scroll down to "Environment Effects" or "Expert+ Environment Effects", and select "No Effects".

[image]<sub>Screenshot from [Beat Saber Official - No Flickering Tutorial (0:46)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGF3efllkCE)</sub>